# What is the origin of the German word Hang?

Tags: etymology

Maybe I lack the knowledge of good sources for German etymology, but I haven't had much luck finding one for the word [Hang](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Hang#German), 'inclination; propensity; bias; a disposition, or liability towards something/someone'.

Is it related to the Low German verb [hangen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hangen#Low_German), '(intransitive, figuratively, with an) to be fond of, to feel strongly about'?

Comment: are you saying, you haven't got *the hang* of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's derived from the precursors of the verb *hängen* ('to hang'), apparently during Late Middle High German times (15th century).** Thus, it's *also* related to the Low German verb *hangen* which has been around since Middle Lower German (13th--16th century).

[Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Hang) says:

> spätmittelhochdeutsch *hanc* = Neigung, zu hängen
>
> *Late Middle High German* hanc *= tendency to hang*

[DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Hang) has a extensive etymological entry for *hängen*, which has its roots in Old High German *hāhan* and *hangēn* (intransitive) ('to hang', both 8th century), and further gives this information for *Hang*:

> ‘Neigung, Geneigtsein, hängende Stellung (des Turners), abschüssige Stelle’ (15. Jh.)
>
> *Inclination, proneness, hanging pose (of a gymnast), precipitous location (15th century)*

stating the same time of origin.

Comment: peek-a-boo. Incidence around the time the book press became public technology is rather biased evidence. The moon also doesn't really disappear once a month, just because you cannot see it.

Comment: I recommend to interpret the compiled evidence and its years as *at least* age of origin.